# Assign a Table to a Person in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 36 people that I need to assign to 3 tables. (12 people on each table)

Can some one please tell me how in excel I can randomly assign a table letter/number to a person?

I have managed to do it with a formula however it gave one letter 16 times, another 8 times etc.

I need it to assign one letter/number no more or less than 12 times.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how have you done it with a formula ?

Comment: It is easy with some helper columns..............is this approach acceptable??

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a method to restict the random to a set number of uses. You could instead, if just using the `=rand()` function, get a number of values and then sort the two columns by the values returned by the random function. Top 12 are table 1 and so forth.

Other options would be look at VBA or just use [Random.org](https://www.random.org/lists/) and enter the list of names. Then hit go and select the first 12 names as table 1 and so forth. Given the nature of the task I suspect this to be much faster and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Place your names in column **A**.  In **C1** enter:

```
="Table" & ROUNDUP(ROW()/12,0)
```

and copy down.  In **D1** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

and copy down.  Finally in **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$36,MATCH(LARGE($D$1:$D$36,ROW()),$D$1:$D$36,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Great approach.  Love the names. :-)

Comment: @Bandersnatch  Thank you ........................ *twice!* ............